# Rowcommand do not fire after clicking button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, rowcommand

**I have already find out the solution, i just want to post it so this may be useful for some people**

This is the button that use command

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="gdvxUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" KeyFieldName="UserName" onrowcommand="gdvxUsers_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Edit" VisibleIndex="0" Width="0px">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imbEdit" runat="server"
                    CommandName = "Edit"
                    ImageUrl="~/images/icon/Edit-icon.png" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

```
    protected void gdvxUsers_RowCommand(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandArgs.CommandName)
        {
            case "Edit":



            break;
        }
    }
```

The Row Command is not fire when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Problem is that on `Page_Load` I use `Databind()` command on the gridview I'm using `rowcommand`, it seems that after `DataBind()`, `rowcommand` is cancelled.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            gdvxUsers.DataSource = GetAllUserAndRole();
            gdvxUsers.DataBind();            
    }
```

So I fix this problem by binding data only on first load.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gdvxUsers.DataSource = GetAllUserAndRole();
            gdvxUsers.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have made `EnableViewState="false"` in grid.

If this is the case, `Rowcommand Event` will also not fire.

You have made `EnableEventValidation="true"` on page.

If this is the case, `RowCommand Event` Will Not Fire, Set This To false.

The solution is to set it to true.

Comment: The Enable ViewState was the key for me, thanks a mill.

Comment: I posted this six years ago and i don't work on ASP.NET Webform anymore but thanks for your reply. This would be useful for other people :)