# How to fire RowCommand when button in gridview in clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify">
    <ItemTemplate>                                
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
             CommandName="Delete" 
             CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>'  >
        </asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If I click delete button `RowDeleting` event is fired. How to fire `RowCommand` event by clicking delete button what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, in 'GrdView_RowCommand' event check CommandName as like below,

```
protected void GrdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
     {
       if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
          {
               //do something
          }
    }
```

[Refer Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773645/in-gridview-how-to-use-rowcommand-event-for-a-button)

[Refer Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606207/rowcommand-do-not-fire-after-clicking-button)